# Grand Cherokee folding mirror mechanism damaged by car wash?

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee, wing-mirrors

I have a 2021 (old platform) Grand Cherokee Overland, which came factory-equipped with power folding mirrors. I just took it through a car wash, during which the passenger-side mirror was pushed into a folded position (driver side unaffected). I noticed this as I exited the wash, and cycled the folding mirrors, during which there was a "thump" and the mirror seems to have restored to its proper position. The owner's manual makes reference to "manually" folding the mirrors, but it's not entirely clear what they are attempting to describe.

Is there some sort of cam-lock device in the folding mechanism where excessive force simply releases the mirror from the power actuator and will re-engage automatically? Would this incident have caused any internal damage, or is this all what the folding mechanism was designed to accommodate?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is pretty standard.  Every electic mirror I've had does this by design.  Just push it back out again if the button does not do it for you.